# How to determine the class and method of a Delayed::Job object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have a bunch of Delayed::Job objects in my DB that are waiting to be executed. How can I inspect them and determine what job (class and method) they contain?

Answer (score 0):

The enqueued jobs are stored in a `delayed_jobs` table, and there is a model `Delayed::Job`, on which you could execute queries.

The column `handler` contains YAML-encoded String of the object, which will do the work.

```
jobs = Delayed::Job.all
jobs.last.handler # will return you the handler object
```

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to app/models/delayed_job.rb:

```
class DelayedJob < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.find_all_by_class_and_method_and_keys(class_name, method_name, keys={})
    search_string="handler like '%object: !ruby/%#{class_name}%method_name: :#{method_name}%' "
    keys.each do |k,v|
      search_string+="and handler like '%#{k}: #{v}\n%'"
    end
    djs=DelayedJob.find_by_sql("select * from delayed_jobs where #{search_string}")
  end

  def self.destroy_all_by_class_and_method_and_keys(class_name, method_name, keys={})
    djs=find_all_by_class_and_method_and_keys(class_name, method_name, keys)
    djs.each do |d|
      d.destroy
    end
  end

end
```

After that, you can just call `DelayedJob.find_all_by_class_and_method_and_keys("MyClassName","my_method_name")` to retrieve just the jobs with the MyClassName class and my_method_name method as active record objects.